# Execute a root command every 24 hours after startup

Tags: ubuntu, cron, root, ubuntu-11.04, crontab

I want to execute a command as root on an Ubuntu 11.04 machine every 24 hours. This machine is not on all of the time, but when it is, it can be left on for days at a time. How should I correctly configure my crontab to execute this command at the desired interval, and is there anything special about executing a cron job as root that I should know about? I am the only person who uses this machine.

Comment: Note that your title seems to ask how you can execute a command 24 hours _after_ each startup, while your question asks about doing it every 24 hours, with no regards to when the system was started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add your script to be executed to directory `/etc/cron.daily` - it will be executed once a day by [`anacron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacron).

Excerpt from `man 8 anacron`:

> Anacron can be used to execute commands periodically, with a frequency specified  in  days.   Unlike  cron(8),  it  does  not assume that the machine is running continuously.  Hence, it can be  used  on  machines that  aren't  running  24  hours  a day, to control daily, weekly, and monthly jobs that are usually controlled by cron.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this. It's been working great.

Answer (score 0):

To edit root's crontab, run:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Fill in a line with e.g.:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/sbin/ntpdate-debian -s
```

This will execute the specified command `ntpdate` with switch `-s` once every stroke of midnight (see `info 'crontab(5)'` for a documentation of the format, or probably just the commented first lines of the crontab itself).

Some small pointers:

- Note that the commands in crontab normally are executed via `/bin/sh`, which on Debian based system is not Bash, but Dash. Be careful to not use [Bashisms](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) in the commands. In my experience it is not uncommon to see incorrect redirects, and incorrect assumptions concerning which characters that need to be escaped.
- It is often a good idea to give complete paths to the binaries since the `PATH` variable might differ between root and your regular user. I have seen situations where one command has shadowed another due to differing `PATH` variables, which is an unnecessary complication.

  It can also be viewed as somewhat of a security risk to simply execute the program that is first in the path lookup, since sloppy configuration might open this up for someone to replace a binary (if one has that kind of rights on the system, one can probably do it anyway to some extent, but nevertheless).

Cron will execute the command every 24 hours, as long as the machine is running at the time. If you want to make the machine "catch up" if it was turned off at a planned execution, you should look at [`anacron`](http://anacron.sourceforge.net/) that has this exact purpose.